# How do I use two async def together

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the code below for sniping deleted messages

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.attachments:
        bob = message.attachments[0]
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        bob.proxy_url, message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
    else:
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
```

But when I add the code below, the snipe command stops working, is the a way for that to not happen?

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=message.created_at,
        title = "[Message Deleted]",
        colour = discord.Colour(0xff0000)
        )
    embed.set_author(name=f'{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{message.author.id} • Message ID: {message.id}")
    embed.add_field(name="Message Content:", value=message.content)
    embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    channel = client.get_channel(825939423061475359)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You can only have one event of a specific type in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one event, you have to combine them both.

```py
@client.event
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.attachments:
        bob = message.attachments[0]
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        bob.proxy_url, message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
    else:
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=message.created_at,
        title = "[Message Deleted]",
        colour = discord.Colour(0xff0000)
        )
    embed.set_author(name=f'{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{message.author.id} • Message ID: {message.id}")
    embed.add_field(name="Message Content:", value=message.content)
    embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    channel = client.get_channel(825939423061475359)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

If you're using `commands.Bot` you can create listeners with the `Bot.listen()` decorator:

```py
@client.listen()
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=message.created_at,
        title = "[Message Deleted]",
        colour = discord.Colour(0xff0000)
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f'{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{message.author.id} • Message ID: {message.id}")
    embed.add_field(name="Message Content:", value=message.content)
    embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    channel = client.get_channel(825939423061475359)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)


@client.listen()
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.attachments:
        bob = message.attachments[0]
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        bob.proxy_url, message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
    else:
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (
        message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
```